# Linux - Exclusive Oracle /tmp directory

Tags: linux

Question about /tmp dir on CentOS, can a user have his/her own "/tmp" directory? how would I change it so that the specific user (Oracle) use that one and not the "public" /tmp one?

Comment: Sure. This is even done by default by pam_systemd: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162900/what-is-this-folder-run-user-1000 ; However, AFAIK, this is only done upon login, not to mention that it ultimately depends on the program which one to use.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That link was some eye-opening reading.  For now the user wants to take a different approach: Enlarge /tmp to 10GB and once he's done, I'd shrink it back down to the normal 1GB, but I am thinking that would be easier done in single user mode.  Do you have any thoughts on this idea?